# How to intercept HTTP request with Java from third party

Tags: java, http, interceptor

I have a enterprise website with a few protected URLs, so not everyone can access it. 
I want to add security protocol for some people who would access this website, they will access it with a cookie for example.

I'd want to put a new server in the middle of the process with a java application that will intercept the HTTP requests, check the cookie, and redirect to the wanted URL if ok.

I have no idea on how to do this... Could you give me some lead ?

Thanks !

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncat.html. Also note that "java" is too broad. What is the technology stack you are using? Plain servlets, jsp, jsf, Java EE, Spring, Vaadin .... ? (to name a few :))

Comment: You should read up on Servlet Filters.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
@muller : the technology used is multiple. For the interceptor part, it's opened. This part is totally a new one, and deals only deals with HTTP requests. That's why I don't really know in which way to go.
I'll read the given doc first ;)

Comment: I post again, because there is something in the process that is totally blurry to me. 

If I want to reach the URL www.toto.com, I want to be able to put a server before, between the client en the final server, so I can imagine that there is some network stuff to do. Am I wrong ?If so, I cannot understand the way that an interceptor could be capable of listen to the good request... Thanks again !